# how to get data from soap into my android

Tags: android, sql, eclipse, soap

Ive build an app that use sql ws to get data. i can get the data but because its a String I dont know how to split it into some verbals.

this is mt soqp rsponse

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:getDataFromSqlResponse xmlns:ns2="http://myAndroidIt.gy.com/">
            <return>id- 2 first name- hanane last name- yniv
</return>
        </ns2:getDataFromSqlResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

how can i put only the id (2)  into verbals?
I want to use it.

thx!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a library like ksoap2-android for calling Soap Webservices. You can add the library to your project with maven like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.code.ksoap2-android</groupId>
  <artifactId>ksoap2-android</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If you don't use maven you can find the download link for the jar [here](https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/HowToUse).

You can use the ksoap2 library to make soap calls like this:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);         

// Here you could add things to your request like this:
request.addProperty("parameter1", 7);
request.addProperty("parameter2", "asdf");
request.addProperty("parameter3", someChildSoapObject);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SSoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
          
HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
```

After you have your response object you can parse the values you need from the response object like this:

```
int id =  Integer.parseInt(response.getPropertySafely("id").toString());
String someOtherProperty = resonse.getPropertySafelyAsString("someProperty");
```

You can find more information about how to use ksoap2-android [here](https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks).

If you don't want to or can't use a soap library i would suggest you use a serializer framework like Simple to deserialize the String. You can find Simple [here](http://simple.sourceforge.net/).
I actually once used Simple to write a small soap framework when it was impossible to use a library so I can recommend this if you can't use ksoap2-android.

Comment: ok i did what you told me and it worked great on my emulator (i put ip 10.0.2.2:8080) but when i try the same app from my mobile device it gets nothing. why is that?

Comment: Well you're gonna need to give me more information than that, otherwise I can't help you out. What exactly is the problem? Are there any exceptions? Can you post lotcat output?